# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't shut down

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, shutdown

I am using an Lenovo ThinkPad with Ubuntu alongside Windows 11. After updating Windows, Ubuntu doesn't shut down and I am stuck at following screen.

[image: Picture of the screen taken from my phone]

I tried to edit the grub file, however this didn't help. Shutting down from the terminal wasn't successful either.
Using an older kernel from the advanced boot options worked smoehow, however i am not sure, if using an older version of the kernel is a good idea.

EDIT

I investigated the last shutdowns with:

```
journalctl -rb -1
```

```
Aug 10 08:52:49 NicosLenovo systemd-logind[720]: Power key pressed.
Aug 10 08:52:21 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: gr: init failed, -110
Aug 10 08:52:21 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2:cmdq: timeout waiting for queue ready
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: user-1000.slice: Consumed 2min 4.516s CPU time.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{85cfac7a-4d53-43e4-b2f8-0f460427de51} -back>
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{85cfac7a-4d53-43e4-b2f8-0f460427de51}"
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Display server starting...
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Removing display ":0" ...
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo sddm[1219]: Display server stopped.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Stopped Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: systemd-oomd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Stopping Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Consumed 1min 42.211s CPU time.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Finished Exit the Session.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Reached target Shutdown.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: app.slice: Consumed 1min 38.816s CPU time.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed Speech Dispatcher Socket.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed Sound System.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed PipeWire Multimedia System Socket.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped target Timers.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped target Sockets.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped target Paths.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped target Basic System.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo systemd[1322]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 00002318
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000026c8
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 00001a97
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 00001822
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000025b9
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000025aa
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000025b9
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000025aa
Aug 10 08:52:20 NicosLenovo kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: sec2: TRACEPC: 000025b9
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue too. I updated my windows 10 but accidentally opened ubuntu during the reboot. Luckily my windows was intact and updated later. But my Ubuntu won't shut down after I do the update and upgrade.

I reinstalled ubuntu formatted the sector. It worked as long as I don't update.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this was done.